# iOS - how to implement crop image like default photo album?

Tags: ios, image, camera, edit, crop

The default crop function in iPhone photo album

[image]

Does any one know how to implement this? I want to crop it before **Use** button is tapped.

[image]

Comment: You can use following third party repository for this. Those provides UI for cropping and scaling photos in iPhone / iPod Touch apps. - [BJImageCropper](https://github.com/barrettj/BJImageCropper) - [SSPhotoCropperViewController](https://github.com/ardalahmet/SSPhotoCropperViewController) - [ImageCropper](https://github.com/iosdeveloper/ImageCropper) - [BFCropInterface](https://github.com/azzikid/BFCropInterface) A combination of [BJImageCropper](https://github.com/barrettj/BJImageCropper) and [SSPhotoCropperViewController](https://github.com/ardalahmet/SSPhotoCropperViewController) would be a

Answer (score 9):

Try one of these:

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=crop

You might find an open source that does exactly that

Comment: Thanks, I've found a useful library, but there is a bug on image orientation on the library that I used

Comment: The life of an iOS developer is not an easy one :)

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to present a `UIImagePickerController` with the ability to crop the picture before picking it. This is built-in into UIImagePickerController, just set the `allowsEditing` property to `YES`. See the documentation for more info http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html.

Comment: I know this property, unfortunately, it not allow me to specify the size to crop

Answer (score 2):

you can use this to crop the image.

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(some rect); 

CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([urImageView.image CGImage], rect);
UIImage *cropedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func cropImageZero(_ completionHandler: (_ img: UIImage)->()){
        let image = UIImage(named: "name")
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: y, width: width, height: height)
        let cgImage = image?.cgImage!.cropping(to: rect)
        let imageNew = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage!)
        completionHandler(imageNew)
}
```

#### image cropping, in Swift 4,

Bonnie's answer is useful