# xamarin ios crop image like Android

Tags: ios, image, xamarin, crop

I'm using xamarin iOS.

I want to take a photo, and afterwards make the posibility for the user to crop the image to any size he wants, like in android:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXapR.png]

or in the galery like this other question:

[iOS - how to implement crop image like default photo album?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16644193/2096139)

I think the answer for that question is pretty good, but all the controlls that I have fond are in Objective-C, and I don't know how to translate it to c# for xamarin...

Does exists some control (or built in option in iOS) to make the crop resizable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've found Obj-C source to accomplish what you want, you can try porting the Obj-C code to C#. It's usually not that tough once you get started. I did it once with an iOS custom alert control: https://github.com/jsauve/SIAlertView.Xamarin. You could compare the source of those projects to get some ideas on how you'd start porting. Either that, or you could use [Objective Sharpie](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/objective_sharpie/) to help you create C# bindings for the Obj-C library. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
float imageWidth = bitmap.Width;
float imageHeight = bitmap.Height;
float width = yourscreenWidth;
float heigth =  yourscreenHeight ;           

var W= width / heigth / (imageWidth / imageHeight);
var W2 = rect.Width() / widt * W;
var H = rect.Height() / heigth;
var cropImageWidth = imageWidth * W2 ;
var cropImageHeight = imageHeight * H ;
var cropImageX = (imageWidth - cropImageWidth) / 2;
var cropImageY = (imageHeight - cropImageHeight) / 2;
Bitmap imageCropped = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(bitmap, (int)cropImageX, (int)cropImageY, 
(int)cropImageWidth, (int)cropImageHeight);
```